# Parsing a Unix timestamp from a binary file

Tags: ruby

I have a byte array `[83, 9, 39, 209]` representing a Unix timestamp, parsed from a binary file.

How can I convert this into an (32-bit) integer?

I've been struggling with #pack and #unpack all night, but am stuck between hex and byte values (the 'N' and 'L' directives aren't giving me what I expect). How can I construct an int from this?

Otherwise is there a different way I should be parsing the file (with hex values)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is that you use [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) to pack a data structure into a sequence of bytes to send over the network or save them to disk and you use [`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) to unpack a sequence of bytes into an in-memory data structure. You have a sequence of four bytes that you want to *unpack* into a 32 bit integer so you're looking for `String#unpack`.

If you had the original bytes then you could say:

```
"\x53\x09\x27\xd1".unpack('N')
```

to get `[1393108945]` and then `Time.at(1393108945)` would give you `2014-02-22 14:42:25 -0800`. That timestamp seems like what you're looking for.

If you're already stuck with that array of *integers* then you could do it by hand with something like:

```
a = [83, 9, 39, 209]
t = a.reverse # Reverse the "byte" order to match `with_index`
     .map.with_index { |e, i| e * 2 ** (8 * i) } # Shift the bits into the right 32 bit integer positions
     .inject(:+) # Add them up to get a single 32 bit integer
```

That will leave you with `1393108945` in `t`. You could also unroll the `Enumerable` wrangling and do it by hand:

```
a[0] * 2 ** (8 * 3) + a[1] * 2 ** (8 * 2) + a[2] * 2 ** 8 + a[3]
```

All the operators make that look a bit like line-noise though.

You'd probably be better off working with the raw bytes and `String#unpack` if you can.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. One of these days I'll find the time to write an actual book.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But that's recreational rather than work and I'm a little outclassed around here :)

Comment: Thanks mu, I think "raw bytes" is an additional source of confusion. `#bytes` gives me integers, while `#chars` gives me the raw values we're looking for, which I can use with `#unpack`. Is #chars how I should be working with the data, then? Or a different approach?

Comment: @SexxLuthor: If you have four bytes in a string (i.e. `"\x53\x09\x27\xd1"`) then you don't need to call `bytes` or `chars` to get "bytes", just unpack the string as-is. If you're reading this data from a binary file then you should have that string in hand.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks, that makes sense. I think one of the other confusing parts was the nature of the text when examining with pry or irb, for example, but I think that's strictly an ASCII rendering issue (capital 'S', horizontal tab, etc.).